# Difference Between ps -ef and ps -auxwww?

Tags: ps

Can anyone explain to me what is the difference between

```
ps -ef
```

and

```
ps -auxwww
```

with some examples?

---

I just want to know the difference between them. I have checked a [post](https://www.interviewbit.com/unix-interview-questions/#ps-ef-vs-ps-auxwww) that provides the information i.e `ps -ef` will not list the processes with a very long command line while `ps -auxwww` will list those processes as well.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately your question is very broad. What did you already try? The header line in the output of both should already explain some of the differences; apart from that I would recommend that you first read the man page. If you then still have questions, please edit your post to elaborate, and most likely a contributor will be able to explain.

Comment: Historically, in UNIX System V and BSD UNIX some commands had different options. (There are more differences between the two families of UNIX systems.) The GNU version of the `ps` command supports both variants. `ps -ef` is a System V variant, `ps -auxwww` or `ps auxwww` is a BSD variant.

Answer (score 1):

`ps` is a very system-dependant  command. There are and have been different flavours for historical reasons.

`ps -ef` is the syntax to get information `e`very process with a `f`uller-format listing on Unices based on AT&T's Unix Support Group (USG), the part of AT&T that was commercialising Unix. Or the SysV syntax if you like though `ps -ef` was already in SysIII in 1980.

It's specified by POSIX but only under the XSI option (which corresponds to the X/Open specification which was an effort to bring some form of standardisation for SysV-based systems, now merged into POSIX).

The closest POSIX equivalent would be `ps -A -o user,pid,ppid,tty,time,args` (missing the `C` (CPU) column).

`ps aux` would be the BSD syntax, from the more *academic* systems based on the original version of Unix developed by AT&T research (Bell Labs). You didn't use `-` there. `a` for *all* processes (not just the ones associated with the current terminal), `u` for *user oriented output* to include additional information, `x` to also include processes not associated with any terminal (Research Unix v3 where `ps` first appeared already had `-x` for that). `w` for *wide* was added much later.

The `procps` `ps` implementation typically found on Linux-based systems tries to conciliate all  those different (and often incompatible) syntaxes, the SysV one, the BSD one, and even more like from HP/UX or AIX, so supports most syntaxes excepts in the cases where one conflicts with another.

The man page on your system will give you all the details of what the various flags mean.

Whether `ps -ef` will truncate or not the command line depends very much on the system, system version and implementation and version of `ps` and whether the output is going to a terminal or not. Some support `-w` to make it wider. On some systems including older versions of Linux, the command line is truncated by the system itself, so you can't easily get it in full if it's very large.

Standardly, you also have the option of specifying the fields you want:

```
ps -A -o pid -o args
```

For instance for just the pid and command line (technically, the list of arguments passed to the last command the process executed though on many systems, processes can also change that arbitrarily) of `A`ll processes.

```
ps -A -o pid= -o args=
```

to skip the header.

Beware not all systems support the same list of fields.

In scripts, I'd recommend sticking to the [POSIX syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html) (avoiding optional features).

And for searching for processes based on some criteria including command line, use `pgrep` (`pkill` to kill them). Those are not standard but are pretty common, and much more reliable to use than processing the output of `ps`.